# How is the property assignment in scala swing implemented

Tags: scala, scala-swing

In scala swing I can do something like the following:

```
val field = new TextField("", 4)
field.text = "Hello"
```

And the assignment is implemented thus:

```
  def text_=(t: String): Unit = peer.setText(t)
```

But if I try my own implementation such as:

```
  case class A(i: Int) {
    def value_=(j: Int) = copy(i = j)
  }
  
  val a = A(3)
  a.value = 3
```

This will not compile for me. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

In Scala 2.13 (and 3) the setter `def value_=` (or `def value_$eq`) seems to work if you declare a field `value`

```scala
case class A(i: Int) {
  val value: Int = 0
  def value_=(j: Int) = copy(i = j)
}
```

or

```
case class A(i: Int, value: Int = 0) {
  def value_=(j: Int) = copy(i = j)
}
```

By the way, it's a little confusing that a setter `value_=` returns `A` rather than `Unit`

```scala
println(a.value = 4) // A(4,0)
```

---

In Scala 2.12 the "setter" `def value_=` (or `def value_$eq`) works if you declare a "getter" too

```
case class A(i: Int) {
  def value = "value"
  def value_=(j: Int) = copy(i = j)
}
```

Comment: Neither approach compiles from me in Scala 2.12. When I try to assign I just get a "reassignment to val" error

Comment: @user79074 It compiles in Scala 3.2.0 https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/dWCITqq7TDO9jbOX2JOXNA/1 https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/dWCITqq7TDO9jbOX2JOXNA/2 and in 2.13.10 https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/dWCITqq7TDO9jbOX2JOXNA/4 https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/dWCITqq7TDO9jbOX2JOXNA/3 You're right, it doesn't compile in 2.12.17 https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/dWCITqq7TDO9jbOX2JOXNA/5 https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/dWCITqq7TDO9jbOX2JOXNA/6

Comment: @user79074 Hmm, I can't reproduce the scala-swing `TextField` behavior in 2.12 at Scastie https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/dWCITqq7TDO9jbOX2JOXNA/10 Something because of Java 17. Will try to reproduce locally.

Comment: @user79074 In Scala 2.12 you have to declare both "setter" and "getter". See the update.